# PHP API Call Results Output To HTML Table

Tags: php, html

I am trying to format the results from my API call in a table. When the page loads, the output is the HTML and the returned API results.

I just need an extra set of eyes as I have been staring at this way too long and made too many changes to get it working.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
//set Header
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://192.168.1.254/api/getinfo';

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/json', 'Authorization: Token 2521dd79c431b7e6551aa13795feafadef450ba4'));

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, json_encode($fields));

//save response to variable $result
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$results = json_decode($result);

        echo '<table class="table table-bordered">'.
                '<thead>';

                    foreach ($results[0] as $key => $value) {
                        echo "<th>$key</th>";
                    }
                echo '</thead>'.
                '<tbody>';
                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                                echo '<td>'. (is_array($value) ? implode(', ', $value) : $value) .'</td>';
                            }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                echo '</tbody>'.
            '</table>';

//decode response in order to access objects
// assuming `$jsonResponse` is your json response variable
// here true will use return response in array format
//$decoded = json_decode($result, true);

// this will return you your response in array
//if($decoded['intCode'] == 200){
//    print_r($decoded['arrProvinceId']);
//}

//echo $results;
?>
```

I tried escaping the quotes, using double quotes and moving the PHP tags around.

Comment: You don't need to set the header to application/json, since the output is HTML (text/html).

Answer (score 0):

Removed the header type ... it sort of works now.  Sorry for the BS post.

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer, but maybe this will help sort out the rest of it.

1. Added the correct content type in the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER option as
   'Content-Type: application/json'.
2. Removed the line curl_setopt($ch,
   json_encode($fields)); as it seems to be unnecessary and incorrect.
3. Added a check for successful JSON decoding using if ($results).
4. Modified the table generation logic to include table row () and
   table header () elements properly.
5. Updated the loop that iterates over the keys of the first result object using array_keys() to ensure the correct column headers are displayed.

And the code:

```
<?php

//set POST variables
$url = "http://192.168.1.254/api/getinfo";

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: Token 2521dd79c431b7e6551aa13795feafadef450ba4",
]);

//save response to variable $result
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$results = json_decode($result, true);

if ($results) {
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach (array_keys($results[0]) as $key) {
        echo "<th>$key</th>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($result as $value) {
            echo "<td>" .
                (is_array($value) ? implode(", ", $value) : $value) .
                "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "Error: Failed to decode JSON response.";
}
?>
```

Comment: James, Thank you so much!
I really appreciate the guidance.